# When deriving work from an uniform electric field and dipole why do we need to integrate it?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, work, dipole, dipole-moment

If the force is constant in a uniform field wouldn't that mean you dont need to integrate to find work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you question is in regards to the torque on a dipole in a uniform electric field, this can only be done by nontrivial integration because the torque is not constant. You can find the torque on the dipole [at this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole#Torque_on_a_dipole). The torque is not constant because the two opposite charges are pushed in opposite directions. When they are in line with the field, this means they are stretched or compressed relative to each other but don't move any more than that. When they are perpendicular to the field, the charges are pushed around their center.

The torque on a simple dipole in a uniform field has a factor of the sine of the angle between them, so the work as the integral has a factor of the cosine. This is consistent with the torque being the cross product and the work being the dot product of the two vectors. This can be seen at the Wikipedia article or in any General Physics book.

Note that in this case, the force of the field on each charge is constant. Each charge has an equal and opposite force. There is no net force but there is net torque as a function of angle. This is why there is no work associated with moving the dipole (by translation) and only with rotating the dipole in the uniform electric field.

Comment: Hi thank you so much for replying. So basically the E field changes due to the R value so although it is uniform the force the dipole experience will change according to the distance? Then why in a capacitor a uniform E field means the force is the same?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "so although it is uniform" above. Are you saying the work needed to move a dipole through a uniform field? Are you asking about the dipole torque equation?

Comment: I am implying that because uniform field produces the same force at every point the work at the dipole should theoretically be the same? Because for constant force work does not need to be integrated. So why would work for a dipole need to be integrated when the only thing that is changing is the dipole position or the "distance" value in the work equation.

Comment: As I explain in my answer, a uniform field does no work on a dipole under translation. This is because the net force is zero, so the integral of zero is zero. However, a uniform field does do work on a dipole under rotation, and that is because a uniform field can exert torque on a dipole. The torque is not any sort of "constant" or "uniform" object, it has a factor of the sine of the angle between the field and the dipole. Finding the total work of this torque thus requires integration. Is that clear?

Comment: Note, I agree with the answer from @Farcher too. I would just say that technically, he is cheating by hiding the integral when he swaps $\vec{F} \cdot d\vec{s}$ for $F \Delta s$, where the second $s$ is a different $s$, "only along the line of force" as he says. That is due to the nature of integrating $\vec{F} \cdot d\vec{s}$ for a uniform $\vec{F}$. I looked at it the traditional way with torque, it is worth noting that the answer can be understood by the "linear motion" of the two charges caused by rotation as opposed to translation as in that answer. I find that interesting.

Comment: This makes so much sense now. I understand it now and thank you so much for helping!

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that an integration is not necessary as the magnitude of the force on each of the charges is constant and the directions of the forces do not change as the dipole rotates, the two forces are a couple.

Thus, in this case the integral $\vec F \cdot d\vec s$ becomes a simple product $F\, \Delta s$, where the displacement is along the line of action of the force.

[image]

Work done by the electric field in rotating the dipole from $\theta = \theta_{\rm initial}$ to $\theta = \theta_{\rm final}$ is

$-2\,q\,E\left(\frac \ell 2 \cos \theta_{\rm final}-\frac \ell 2 \cos \theta_{\rm initial}\right ) = q\,\ell\,E(\cos \theta_{\rm initial}-\cos \theta_{\rm final})$